# Importing files into R: skip missing files

Tags: r, import, error-handling

Within a longer script, I am importing files into R. Unfortunately sometimes a file is missing (because they are generated with another program within a loop and sometimes the other program doesn't perform well). Then I get the error:  "cannot open the connection... cannot open file "xy.z": No such file or directory", and the entire script stops. In this case, I would like to just skip this round, not read this file and continue the skript. How can I do that?

Thanks!

Comment: Use `try` or `tryCatch`.

Comment: There's also `file.exists` and `file.info`